# Transition on Stretching Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with some content in it, and I am showing a button with jQuery. I want to fade it in thus I used:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#button').css('opacity', 1);
}, 100);
```

First, on html, I have set the button's html to `display:none; opacity: 0` I have achieved showing/hiding button, however when it shows, it's making the div stretch instantly. Instead, I want the parent div to expand with transition.

I have created a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7450/ . In this example, when I press the trigger button, I want the button to fade in as well as applying transition on  the parent div.

Comment: The way you designed this is not ideal, you should not be using `display: none;` in transitions or animations. This will cause redrawing in your browser, and you cannot transition properties with binary settings, `display` just switches between states (ex: none/block), not between values like `opacity` does.

Comment: Yes, I have just updated my code, upgrading the fiddle now

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the jQuery's `.fadeIn()`? Like so: `jQuery('#button').fadeIn(500)`

Comment: Its not the fadein the problem. It's the parent div. I want to make a transition while it's expanding, not just snap to its new position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimal performance, when using `transitions` and `animations` in CSS, you should stick to `opacity` and `transform` instead of `display: none;` and `width/height`.

Will quote the comment I stated above:

> The way you designed this is not ideal, you should not be using
>   display: none; in transitions or animations. This will cause redrawing
>   in your browser, and you cannot transition properties with binary
>   settings, display just switches between states (ex: none/block), not
>   between values like opacity does.

---

What you could do is separate your content, sharing the same background color to simulate it is the same container.

Then use `transform` and the `scale()` function.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
jQuery('#trigger').click(function() {
  jQuery('.bottom-content').addClass('open');
})
```

```css
.top-content,
.bottom-content {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.bottom-content {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in;
  transform-origin: top;
}
.bottom-content.open {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
.bottom-content.open #otherButton {
  opacity: 1;
}
#otherButton {
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 10s;
  transition-delay: 250ms;
  /* Separated for clarity purposes, wait for parent transition to end before starting this one*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.addressfinder.co.nz/assets/v2/widget.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <section class="top-content">
      <button id="trigger">
        Trigger
      </button>
      <br />Lalala La
      <br />Lalala La
      <br />Lalala La
      <br />
    </section>
    <section class="bottom-content">
      <button id="otherButton">
        Test Btn
      </button>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is overkill. Just use `.fadeIn()` and forget the opacity and transition settings completely.  If you want to have the `div` expand separate from the button, just apply the effect to the div and then trigger the button effect at the end of the `div` effect. This snippet does the same thing as the accepted answer without any of the CSS troubles:

```js
$(function(){
   jQuery('#otherButton').hide();
   jQuery('#two').hide();
});
$('#trigger').click(function() {
 $('#two').slideDown(2000, function(){
       $('#otherButton').fadeIn();
    });
 
})
```

```css
#container, #two {
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
      <br>

      Lalala La<br>
      Lalala La<br>
      Lalala La<br>
      <div id="two">
        <button id="otherButton">Test Btn</button>&nbsp;
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My main problem is the transitioning the parent div. Fadein is working just fine. But how about the parent div transition?

Comment: @senty As I said, just apply the fadeIn() to the parent div instead of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the jquery:

```
jQuery('#trigger').click(function() {
    jQuery('#otherButton').slideDown(300).css('opacity', 1);
})
```

Note that I used the `slideDown()` function rather than `show()`. Using a transition function allows you to set an execution time. `show()` simply toggles the css `display` property, but you can not transition the `display` property.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/atg5m6ym/7454/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding CSS with jQuery, you can simply add a class instead.

Set this class to whatever properties you want on it, us as:

```
.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7456/

Now, CSS doesn't like to transition when switching `display: none;` so instead I have simply set the `height: 0;` and only applied necessary styling on the `.is-visible` class.